# Subdomain not listed to add (as custom domain)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, subdomain, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I need to add sgtm.mydomain.com as a custom domain (to use with GTM server)

[how im adding the subdomain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdKT4.png)
When I write "sgtm.mydomain.com", it takes me to verification in Google Console.

And since I already have the naked domain verified, it auto verifies instantly.

However, the subdomain does not appear on Google Cloud Console / Custom Domain for me to add.

Even after updating domain list; even after 24 hours.

[subdomain is not listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsGWa.png)

I've searched everywhere and found nothing :(

Could you please help me?

I've tried re-verifying the domain, and waiting.

I expected the subdomain to show on that list.

However only the main domain shows.

Comment: Most of the time, the way you verify the domains is adding some TXT records in the DNS and looking for the domain I don't see any, only for the naked one. Are you the owner of the naked domain?

Comment: @Puteri I am the owner of the naked domain, and it is already verified on GSConsole. 

When I try to verify the subdomain, it automatically verifies (because the naked domain is mine). So it does not ask for a TXT confirmation (which is what's also asked on the video tutorial I'm following)